# How can I force users to a particular subdomain to log in for MU (Multisite)?

Tags: plugins, multisite, admin, login, ssl

I have a Multi-Site installation of Wordpress, with multiple subdomains, but only one of the subdomains has an SSL certificate.

The domains are such:

```
www.example.com
blog1.example.com
blog2.example.com

secure.example.com
```

`secure.example.com` is the subdomain which has a SSL cert installed.

If someone types in `blog1.example.com/wp-admin/dashboard.php`, how can I force them to `secure.example.com/wp-admin` and then after they log in redirect them back to `blog1.example.com/wp-admin/dashboard.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Peters Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/) to redirect users after login I have used it before and works well.

You could redirect users to the secure area by adding the below to your .htaccess file :

```
Redirect 301 blog1.example.com/wp-admin/dashboard.php secure.example.com/wp-admin
```

Comment: you might be headed in the right direction with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a wildcard SSL certificate. It allows an unlimited number of subdomains to be secured for your main domain.

Then I would force SSL login in wp-config.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

[Administration Over SSL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL)

Comment: thanks but not looking to go the wildcard ssl route.

Comment: May I ask why not? Seems like that would be the quickest and simplest solution for your problem.